# Can't resize content in the resizeable window. Firstly it was not resizeable

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

I can't resize content of the resizeable *TracePro 7* window on Windows 10 - on Windows 7 it have been OK! Window is resizeable, font size is fixed.

Install the program that resize the window. And resize it with content. Firstly it was not resizeable.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Please try to improve your question a bit... Have you installed a program that resizes non resizeable windows on W10? TracePro 7 window wasn't resizeable on W7?

Comment: Yes I have! Autoresizer and a lot of others! But in all cases the effect was the same! On another windows 10 content is sceled properly.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you're asking. If you want Windows 10 to apply the fuzzy faux-DPI scaling to the program, [see my answer over here](http://superuser.com/a/1018284/380318).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the program supports resizing but doesn't handle the large fonts system setting. Try setting the font size to 100% in the Control Panel.

Comment: It was already on 100%. I can not make it smaller may it could help? Firstly I was thinking it is because of java update.

Comment: @IgorSmolin, interaction between Java and new operating systems may yield unpredictable results... Try installing an older Java version or the latest one. Try increasing the font size (maybe the developers of the program had large fonts and didn't account for regular ones).

Comment: Thank you. I try, but nothing happens. I try this program in another windows 10 and its working. I do not even know what can cause this think. I have been delete the latest java version.

Comment: @IgorSmolin, try comparing all characteristics of those two Windows 10 computers. Check Java version, 32-bit/64-bit, screen resolution, large font setting, desktop theme. Try adjusting your computer to the same settings as another one until everything is the same.