# Force an application to run in a lower resolution to native Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, scaling, high-dpi, 4k-resolution, cad

I'm trying to use Solid Edge ST8 on a 4k laptop. In 4K the application becomes almost unusable.

Screen shot of Solid Edge ST8 running at 4k:

[image]

When I go into the Windows settings and change the resolution to 1080 and restart Solid Edge ST8 becomes much more user friendly.

Solid Edge ST8 at 1080:

[image]

At both resolutions 'Disable display scaling on high DPI setting' on the compatibility tab is checked.

Is there a way I can force only this application to run at 1080 without changing the whole system resolution and restarting every time?

Comment: Are you asking how to make Windows do the blurry stretch effect on that program? If so, see [this question](http://superuser.com/q/1002267/380318).

Answer (score -1):

Let's see. I saw 4K screen and it was small, but still marginally comfortable, 2K screen and a bit pixelated in true size, but you may not like it. So I'll suggest the resolution of 2560x1440 or 2880x1800, try these two and see which one is better.

Comment: The actual question: "Is there a way I can force only this application to run at 1080 without changing the whole system resolution and restarting every time?"

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: @Chris - How does one accomplish this?  You have an odd obsession with resolution questions, but the problem is, almost all of your answers are at best vague comments on the subject.