# On Windows 10, why are some programs not scaling on second monitor?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, scaling

Per the 2 screenshots below, Adobe Acrobat DC and Internet Explorer failed to scale correctly on my second monitor because the menus are too big. Under `Settings > System > Display`, I cannot decrease 'the size of text, apps, and other items' because the slider is already at the extreme left. But some other programs (MS Office) does scale correctly.

Display adapters: Intex HD Graphics 530, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M with Driver Version 354.74
Monitor 1 (with correct scaling): Lenovo Ideapad Y700, 3840 x 2160
Monitor 2 (with imperfect scaling): Dell E153FP, 1024 x 768

[image]

Comment: It will likely help if you can provide details on the video card (s) in use, driver version(s) for them, the monitors makes/models and the resolutions in use.

Comment: @Argonauts Done. I will add the driver version(s) tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why some programs misbehave on different screens but some don't

Modern Windows applications should include a [manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191(v=vs.85).aspx), which is an XML document that's usually embedded in the main EXE file. Manifests declare several important things, including whether the program will ask to be UAC-elevated and, more relevantly, the level of DPI awareness. If a program understands how to redraw itself for different dots-per-inch settings, it is DPI aware.

[This Old New Thing article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160617-00/?p=93695) mentions the three levels of DPI awareness available on Windows 8.1 and up: no awareness (in which case the system will scale the program up, producing blurriness), system DPI awareness, and per-monitor DPI awareness. The difference between those last two is that per-monitor-DPI-aware programs need to redraw themselves depending on which monitor they're on, since different monitors can have different DPIs. System-DPI-aware programs scale themselves for the highest-DPI monitor, then the system scales them down as appropriate.

I inspected the manifests of the programs you mentioned by searching with a hex editor for the string `<dpiAware`. These are my results:

- Internet Explorer 11: `True/PM` (per-monitor aware)
- Microsoft Word 2016: `True` (system aware)
- Adobe Reader XI: `True/PM`

Word, therefore, is partially handled by the system, which explains why it works as you expect. The other programs *should* handle themselves, but evidently they messed up. Per-monitor-DPI-aware programs receive information about a monitor change by the [`WM_DPICHANGED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd464659(v=vs.85).aspx) window message, but these apparently don't do the right thing in response to that.

Further reading: [Writing DPI-Aware Desktop and Win32 Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266)

#### How to fix it

It's [possible](https://superuser.com/a/1018284/380318) to use the compatibility infrastructure to force blurriness (i.e. make the programs not DPI aware at all), but it seems that you want to make these programs only partially DPI-aware (i.e. use the system level). The only I way I can think of to do that is to whack the EXE with a hex editor and change the manifest. I like [XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm), no affiliation.

Run your hex editor as administrator and open the program file you want to change. Search for `<dpiAware`, then read a bit ahead until you find `True/PM` (or a different capitalization of the same). It's probably followed immediately by the `</dpiAware>` closing tag, so we'll write over it like so:

```
Old: True/PM</dpiAware>
New: True</dpiAware>
```

Make sure to overwrite the extra space (`re>`) with spaces. You might have to fiddle the file permissions before you save. Once the file is changed, it will be only a system-DPI-aware program.

It appears that the build of Internet Explorer that comes with Windows 10 uses [`SetProcessDpiAwareness`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302122) rather than a manifest to set the DPI awareness. Therefore, we need to get a little more serious with the hex editing. Search for `windowsSettings`, then move your cursor to immediately after the closing bracket of the previous `application` tag. Overwrite with all of this:

```
<windowsSettings><dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware></windowsSettings></application><compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"><application><!--
```

Once you're done, it should look like this (I highlighted the new part in red and placed the blue cursor at the start of the changed portion):

[image: iexplore.exe changed]

That takes advantage of the extra spaces and comments in the default manifest to insert our new setting and move the `compatibility` element forward a bit. When `dpiAwareness` is set in the manifest, the `SetProcessDpiAwareness` function will have no effect.

There is a chance that Windows Resource Protection will roll back the changes, so if the program is automatically reverted, you might need to set up a script to recopy the new version over it.

**Caution!** It's very important that you overwrite rather than insert or delete characters. Inserting or deleting will shift the rest of the executable data, breaking a lot of things. If you make a transcription error, do not press Backspace or Delete. Instead, move your cursor back and overwrite your error with the correct character(s). If you haven't used a hex editor before, you should make a back-up of the EXE file before modifying it.

Comment: Thank you deeply. Sorry to trouble you again: XVI32 is impeding me from Saving. To avoid protracting this post, I posted the problem at http://superuser.com/q/1100160/269574? Can you please see it?

Comment: No problem. Sorry, but as you predicted, `There is a chance that Windows Resource Protection will roll back the changes, so if the program is automatically reverted`. You appear correct (as always), because IE has reverted the code and also the Permission settings (that I questioned separately). How easy is it to preclude this reversion? Maybe it is easiest if I cease using IE?

Comment: @Timere Sadly, I don't know of a safe way to disable WRP. Do make sure that you've changed the owner of the file from TrustedInstaller to Administrators (in addition to changing the file permissions). Alternatively, switching to a different browser might be the way to go. I've deleted my obsolete comments.

Comment: Hi again. I forgot to ask: how did you redden the text string? I ask because I am trying to do the same for another similar problem: http://superuser.com/q/1127953/269574

Comment: @Timere When a character is highlighted (with the blue box), holding Shift while pressing the arrow keys (to move) turns the traversed text red.