# In XVI32, why is 'File access denied' still after selecting 'Run as Administrator'?

Tags: windows-10

This question concerns and follows the advice [here](https://superuser.com/a/1099680/269574) about scaling on Internet Explorer. I right-clicked on XVI32 to `Run as Administrator`, then opened XVI32 and effected the steps. The narrow green arrow indicates the start of the Overwriting. But then when I clicked 'save', the following error message appeared:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because iexplore.exe is owned by TrustedInstaller (NT Service\TrustedInstaller). You may have to [take ownership](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659(v=ws.11).aspx) of the file first (and backup the file) before modifying.

After editing, change the ownership back to `NT Service\TrustedInstaller`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this](https://superuser.com/a/1100184/269574) answer, I Googled myself how to 'Take Ownership' and found [this](https://www.techperiod.com/take-ownership-of-files-folders-windows/).

But the solution was simply to Right-Click the .exe file, then access the `Security` tab, and then to allow `Permissions for Everyone` by using `To change permissions, click Edit.` [image]

Comment: Thanks for the update. if you can can change the Permissions, then you (or Administrators group) is currently the owner of the file. Out of the box, TrustedInstaller owns the file, and changing the ownership is required before adding yourself (or Everyone) Full Control Permissions.

Comment: @w32sh Thank you for your comment.