# Override high DPI settings for Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows-10, windows-media-player, high-dpi

I am using Windows Media Player for playing music files, because there does not seem any decent free music player for Windows. VLC's interface sucks. Groove Music, which Microsoft is replacing WMP with, sucks, too; it does not even support file drag-and-drop.

The problem is that WMP does not work well with high-DPI. the slider is too thin to click and when the window is maximised, it flickers. For normal application EXE's, there is the "Compatibility" tab in the Properties so that I can override the high-DPI settings. But for some reason, that thing does not exist for WMP. Is there anyway to access the setting so that I can make WMP's window get doubled (The "System (Enhanced)" option in the drop-down menu)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Windows Media Player is not being developed, so you are limited to what the options provide. Did you try in WMP Options, Devices, Display and adjust the Display Options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a copy of `wmplayer.exe` into the same Windows Media Player directory. The copy will have a Compatibility tab but otherwise work the same. (You could also hack up the EXE manifest with a hex editor to change its DPI awareness declaration, but making a copy is much easier!)

Unfortunately, GDI (enhanced system) scaling causes a big mess for this application:

[image: text ellipsized, buttons blacked out]

But system scaling is fine, just blurry:

[image: correct layout, blurry]

---

If you need to modify the DPI awareness of the original executable though (e.g. because of file association issues), we have to [break out the hex editor](https://superuser.com/a/1099680/380318)—I like [XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm). First, assign ownership of and full access to the `wmplayer.exe` file to the Administrators group. Make a back-up copy in case you make a mistake or want to revert the changes.

Run XVI32 as administrator and open `wmplayer.exe`. Press Ctrl+F to open the Find dialog. Search for the text string `<dpiAwareness` with the "as Unicode Latin" box unchecked. Click the opening angle bracket in the right pane to make sure that pane is active (white background). Tap the spacebar until you have overwritten the entire tag `<dpiAwareness>PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>` with spaces. (Do not press Delete or Backspace!) This removes the DPI awareness declaration and causes Windows to apply system scaling. Save the changes with Ctrl+S.

For completeness' sake: GDI scaling can be applied by adding a `gdiScaling` tag. (This would again produce ugly results for Windows Media Player, but might be useful for other programs.) Scroll up a tiny bit and overwrite the "2016" in the previous tag's `xmlns` attribute with "201**7**", then immediately after its closing angle bracket, overwrite the spaces with `<gdiScaling>true</gdiScaling>`. When you're done, it will look like this (new tag highlighted in red, attribute change selected in blue):

[image: gdiScaling tag added, 6 changed to 7]

Comment: This is funny. If I just change the name of the wmplayer.exe to something else, the compatibility tab appears. And I copied a dummy exe into the directory and changed its name to wmplayer.exe, its icon changed to that of WMP and the compatibility tab disappeared (it, of course, had the tab when it was in its original directory). It seems that almost the Window itself is doing some sort of special treatment for a file whose path is ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" and actively trying to prevent people from using the compatibility tab. I know that MS is not

Comment: updating WMP to support high DPI, but why are they trying to prevent people from using the compatibility feature with WMP? The compatibility feature is exactly for this kind of old abandoned application, isn't it?

Comment: Strangely, it seems that they did *try* to update it for high DPI - the program's manifest specifies the most up-to-date DPI awareness level, `PerMonitorV2`, which [was introduced in](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/04/04/high-dpi-scaling-improvements-desktop-applications-windows-10-creators-update/) Windows 10 1703 - they just missed some spots.

Answer (score 0):

With Windows Media Player 12, you can make it DPI aware by editing the registry AppCompatFlags:

1. Press Windows + R type in `regedit`, enter and go to:

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`

2. Right-click on the key called `Layers` and create a new string value.
3. Name the string `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe`
4. Right-click on the newly created string and select `Modify..` and then insert the word `HIGHDPIAWARE` and select `Ok`.
5. Restart Windows Media Player for the changes to take effect

This fix can also work for `mmc.exe` so that all Microsoft Management Console-enabled applications can be DPI-aware.

Comment: I believe the `DPIUNAWARE` flag (to subject the application to system scaling) would be what this question asked for. Unfortunately, when I tested on Windows 10 2004, application compatibility flags did not seem to apply to `wmplayer.exe`.